# Python(Django) giving error while pushing on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am new to heroku as well as python (Django). i have made an app in django and want to push on heroku. but on `git push heroku master` it giving me this error.

```
    Writing objects: 100% (245/245), 10.37 MiB | 110.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 245 (delta 35), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing Python-2.7.13
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        /app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda
all: line 5: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to djangoshopnror.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/djangoshopnror.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://git.heroku.com/djangoshopnror.git'
```

i have requirements.txt file and runtime.txt file.
**runtime.txt** look like this

```
Python-2.7.13
```

and **requirements.txt** look like this

```
BestBuyAPI==0.0.51
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.9
django-cors-headers==2.0.2
djangorestframework==3.6.2
djangorestframework-jwt==1.10.0
ebaysdk==2.1.4
gunicorn==19.7.1
lxml==3.7.3
psycopg2==2.7.1
PyJWT==1.5.0
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.7.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
wapy==1.0.0
whitenoise==3.3.0
```

one weired thing is when i change runtime.txt with python version 3.5.x it works. but due to some reasons i have to use python 2.7.x .
can anyone have answer about this. any suggestion or help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: Did you tried `heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL` ?

Comment: Yes i have tried all these stuff which is suggested in similar questions.

Comment: Found my mistake.. That was silly one. in my runtime.txt file i wrote Python-2.7.12 while pyhton-2.7.12 was assumed. this silly error was giving birth to all other.. Solved now :)